# Equilibrium Index in Python 2.7

Tags: python

I was given a demo task to do in Codility, and I am having some trouble trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. The task:

*Working in Python 2.7 Environment*

A zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given. An equilibrium index of this array is any integer P such that 0 ≤ P < N and the sum of elements of lower indices is equal to the sum of elements of higher indices, i.e.

A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[P−1] = A[P+1] + ... + A[N−2] + A[N−1].

Sum of zero elements is assumed to be equal to 0. This can happen if P = 0 or if P = N−1.

For example, consider the following array A consisting of N = 8 elements:

```
A[0] = -1
A[1] =  3
A[2] = -4
A[3] =  5
A[4] =  1
A[5] = -6
A[6] =  2
A[7] =  1
```

P = 1 is an equilibrium index of this array, because:

```
A[0] = −1 = A[2] + A[3] + A[4] + A[5] + A[6] + A[7]
```

P = 3 is an equilibrium index of this array, because:

```
A[0] + A[1] + A[2] = −2 = A[4] + A[5] + A[6] + A[7]
```

P = 7 is also an equilibrium index, because:

```
A[0] + A[1] + A[2] + A[3] + A[4] + A[5] + A[6] = 0
```

and there are no elements with indices greater than 7.

P = 8 is not an equilibrium index, because it does not fulfill the condition 0 ≤ P < N.

Write a function:

def solution(A)

that, given a zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers, returns any of its equilibrium indices. The function should return −1 if no equilibrium index exists.

In response I wrote the following:

```
def solution(A):
    if len(A) == 0: #If we're working with an empty list, the method should give us an empty list message and terminate there
        return "Empty list, no integers to work with"
    else:
        equi = []
        x = 0
        length = len(A)
        rightSum = []
        leftSum = []
        while x < length:
            for i in A:
                rightSum = A[1:i-1]
                leftSum = A[i+1:length-2]
                if sum(rightSum) == sum(leftSum):
                    equi.append(i)
                    return equi
                else:
                    return -1
            x += 1
    pass

solution([-1,3,-4,5,1,-6,2,1])
```

When I complied the code, I kept getting -1 for the test list, even though I should be getting equi[1,3,7].

Another question, why do I need the 'pass' keyword at the end of the method?

I should add, I am extremely new to Python coding and coding in general. Any help y'all can provide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the type of the data your function must return. It is a list of equilibrium indexes.

This means that every `return` statement in your function must return a list. Never a number, never a string.

For an empty list, there are no possible equilibrium indexes; `return []`.

When you find an equilibrium index, you append it to your `equi` list, as you correctly do, *and go on*. Do not `return` from within the `while` loop. The first `return` statement ends the function execution.

When your loop ends because you've looked through all the indexes, the `equi` list will contain all equilibrium indices the loop has found. Now, after the loop, it's time to `return equi`, instead of the useless `pass`.

(For bonus points, you can calculate the sum of the list once, and notice that moving an index to the right adds one element to the left sum and subtracts the same element from the right sum. This way, you won't have to `sum` each sub-list every time; the performance of the algorithm will be linear instead of quadratic.)

Comment: Thank you 9000, that was really helpful suggestion about the bonus points. I didn't even think about just subtracting the index value from the overall sum. For future reference, just how much of a difference will linear vs quadratic save on performance, overhead, etc.? I haven't gotten there yet, but I would imagine any improvement in performance and/or decrease in overhead would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is sane, but you're tripping over some of the language's syntax.

I've tried my best to help your code while commenting it:

```
def solution(A):
    if len(A) == 0: #If we're working with an empty list, the method should give us an empty list message and terminate there
        return "Empty list, no integers to work with"
    else:
        equi = []
        x = 0
        length = len(A)
        rightSum = []
        leftSum = []
        # while x < length: (removed)
        # When we do for i in A, we're already iterating over each element i of the list A.
        # As such, there's no need for the while loop.
        for i in A:
            # You switched right and left sum; elements at the 'left' are at the beginning of the list
            # I also switched the name of the lists to leftList and rightList, to be more descriptive
            # (a list and a sum are different things)
            # I switched the i that was in the indexes to x. i is the integer on the list we're iterating over;
            # its position on the list, on the other hand, is being counted with x.
            leftList = A[0:x]  # Go from 0, since you want to count the first element.
            # We could also ommit the first index and it would begin from the first element
            rightList = A[x+1:]  # If we ommit the second index, it'll go until the last element
            if sum(leftList) == sum(rightList):
                # I changed equi.append(i) to equi.append(x), because i is the value we're iterating over, while
                # x is the counter (index) of the number being currently evaluated
                equi.append(x)
                # return equi (removed)
                # We don't want to return here. When we call return, the function exits!

            # What this would do is exit the function if the sum of the left list wasn't equal to the sum of the right.
            # This isn't what we want, so we'll just remove this
            # else: (removed)
            #     return -1 (removed)
            x += 1

        # No pass needed; that's another thing entirely, just a nil instruction

        # Now the loop is done, we have appended to equi all the equilibrium values.
        # It's time to exit the function by returning the list of equi values.
        # Since we must return -1 if no equilibrium indices exist, then we have to check for that as well
        if len(equi) == 0:
            return -1
        else:
            return equi

sol = solution([-1, 3, -4, 5, 1, -6, 2, 1])
print(sol)  # [1, 3, 7]
```

There are a couple other minor things that could be improved for readability (variable naming conventions, using `enumerate`), but for the sake of brevity and simplicity, I've included just what makes it work.

Comment: Thank you Pedro for your coding hints. Hopefully, as I get better I can code like a true Python developer! As for the enumerate(), I was under the impression it merely printed out the values in a list, dic, tuple, etc. I can certainly see how useful it can be, but I can't see how it useful in this scenario, atm.

Comment: @Ram `enumerate` lists the value alongside with the iteration number, basically the same as your x counter does. So instead of using the `x`, you'd do `for x, i in enumerate(A)` and then just remove the `x = 0` and `x += 1` and it'd still work the same; it auto-declares and auto-increments each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

just simply you can do is :

```
a=[-1, 3, -4, 5, 1, -6, 2, 1]

for i in range(len(a)):

     print("sum of digits at Left  side of the index {} is : {}"  .format(i, sum(a[0:i]))) 

     print("sum of digits at right side of the index {} is : {}" .format(i,sum(a[i+1:len(a)])))

     if  sum(a[0:i])==sum(a[i+1:len(a)]):
        print("My Equilibirium Index is : {} ".format(i))
```